# Prevent form submit when there are errors from asyncValidation

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

I am using React-admin that relies upon redux-forms to validate its forms. I am using `asyncValidation` and `asyncBlurFields` to do server-side validation before the user submits something.

The validation is working when the focus leaves the field that is validated. However, if the user fills in a wrong value into the field and then clicks the submit button (before the focus changes), the form is submitted before the error is triggered.

Here the form:

```
<SimpleForm
  basePath={basePath}
  redirect="list"
  resource={resource}
  record={record}
  save={save}
  asyncValidate={asyncValidate}
  asyncBlurFields={["price"]}
>
  <DisabledInput source="id" />
  <TextInput source="flavor" />
  <ReferenceInput
    source="categoryId"
    reference="categories"
    validate={[required()]}
  >
    <SelectInput optionText="name" {...props} />
  </ReferenceInput>
  <NumberInput source="price" validate={[number(), minValue(0)]} />
</SimpleForm>
```

And here the asyncValidate function:

```
const asyncValidate = async (values, dispatch, props, field) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (field === "price") {
      const res = await dataProviderFactory(GET_ONE, "categories", {
        id: values.categoryId
      });
      const data = await res.data;
      if (values.price && data.price_by_size)
        return reject({ price: "price do not allowed" });
      return resolve();
    }
  });
};
```

Is there any property (in react-admin or redux-forms) that could prevent the form submission before the response from asyncValidation?

Comment: Have you tried moving `return resolve();` out from the `if (field === "price") {` conditional? This is not likely to solve the issue, but if the value of the variable field is not price, it won't resolve.

Comment: The function only triggers when the fields are in the `asyncBlurFields` array. So, it is working fine inside the `if`, thank you.